# Clang Default Search Path with Xcode Command-Line-Tools Installed

Tags: macos, clang, command-line-tool

How do I get the default clang search paths to reference the installed command-line-tools framework directories?

Upon installing the MacOS/Xcode command-line-tools, I expected the `clang` default framework search paths to be updated to the location of the SDK frameworks.  To something like:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

instead I still have the defaults:

```
$ echo | clang -v -E -
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.15.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -ggnu-pubnames -target-linker-version 520 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0 -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public -Wno-atimport-in-framework-header -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/ebg -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 261 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.15.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o - -x c -
clang -cc1 version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12) default target x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

even if I explicitly specify the `clang` location from the tool's /usr/bin I get:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list
```

```
$ ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX
MacOSX.sdk/      MacOSX10.14.sdk/ MacOSX10.15.sdk/
```